# When column entry is "other' then replace with entry from another column

Tags: sql, replace, sql-update

I hope someone can help (this is my first time posting!). Basically I want to do the following:
when the entry in column a is 'other' replace with the entry in column b

I have tried numerous things with no success. This was most recent attempt:

`select  column_a, column_b from [data_table]  update  set column_a = column_b where column_a = 'other'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to change the data in the database, or you just want the report to reflect the data you want.

Just for SELECT into a report:

```
SELECT 
  column_a
, CASE column_a
    WHEN 'other' THEN column_b
    ELSE column_a
  END AS column_a
, column_b
FROM data_table
;
```

To change the data in the database:

```
UPDATE data_table
SET column_a = column_b
WHERE column_a = 'other'
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work,

And please include the errors, or issues in more detail.

```
select column_a, column_b from data_table
update data_table
set column_a = column_b
where column_a = 'other' ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that but it is saying 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'update'.

Comment: @rozzo In that case you will need to create a procedure, if you haven't already.